# Magento - Display product count views?

Tags: magento

I am using magento 1.9 and i am trying to display the views of the product in the product view page.

Here is what code i am using right now but it's not displaying anything:

```
<?php $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output'); ?>
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<?PHP echo $_product->getViews();?>
```

Is it possible to display the number of the views of the displayed product or where i am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `views` is not an attribute that is loaded with the product, or exists at all.  You will likely need to create some custom logic to get the counts from the `log_url_info` table.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an observer for `catalog_product_load_after` and add `views` to the `$_data` array with

```
$product  = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$read     = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
$select   = $read->select()
    ->from(
        $resource->getTableName('log/url_info_table'),
        'COUNT(*) views'
    )
    ->where('url LIKE "%catalog/product/view/id/' . $product->getId() . '"');

$result = $read->query($select)->fetch();

$product->setData('views', $result['views']);
```

Comment: My product URL is looking like this: http://mymagento.com/708042.html Does it change anything to the code or not ?

Comment: No, Magento stores the full controller/action url

Comment: When i execute this code i get error - Fatal error: Call to a member function getEvent() on a non-object